# What is the middle column stands for in the output of "gdb-> info register"?

Tags: assembly, disassembly, cpu-registers

In the book of *Art of Exploitation* by Erickson, at page 28, the following output of dgb is given,

[image]

I understand that the left most column gives the name of the registers, and the rightmost column gives the current value of that register, but what is the middle column stands for ?

Initially I thought it is the memory adress that value of the register is stored, but then seeing that both the value on the middle column and the right column of eip register is the same, I'm little confused, since this register points to the memory address which the processor is reading.

Comment: Middle column is the value in hexadecimal. Right column is the value in the format gdb thinks most appropriate (hex for pointers, decimal for the others).

Comment: @Jester I wasn't asking what the format of that particular data; rather what is the meaning of that data ? what that represents ?

Comment: The second and third columns have the *same* value—the value of the register—only in different formats.

Comment: @prl Oh, I see.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center column is the current value of the register as a 32 bit hexadecimal value.